# how to load data set into libsvm in C#

Tags: c#, libsvm

I have downloaded SVM in C# from Libsvm, but I don't know where to load my data to perform classification, I would like to know how to load the data set into SVM and run it.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using [libsvm.net](https://github.com/nicolaspanel/libsvm.net)

You have to ways to load your data :

---

**First way - Using a file data set**, called "TRAINING_FILE.txt"

Note : This method assume your file is correctly formated. See [here](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/) for some good samples.

```
var TRAINING_FILE = "C:\\[your_local_path]\\TRAINING_FILE.txt";
var data_set = ProblemHelper.ReadAndScaleProblem(TRAINING_FILE);
```

If you don't want to scale, just use following instruction :

```
var data_set = ProblemHelper.ReadProblem(TRAINING_FILE);
```

Then, you finally have to create your SVM

```
var svm = new C_SVC(data_set, [most_appropriate_Kernel], c_parameter);
```

---

**Second way - Formating the dataset yourself**

Note : This method use Linq, make sure you added the System.Ling reference.

You can build your data_set line by line using the following code :

```
var vy = new List<double>();
var vx = new List<svm_node[]>();
foreach (var line_i in your_data_source)
{
   vy.Add(line_i.Y); // double value representing the class for the given experience

   List<svm_node> x = new List<svm_node>();
   for(int j = 0 ; j < NB_ATTRIBUTES ; j++) // Save values for each attributes
   {
      var attributeValue = line_i.X[j]; // value of the corresponding attribute
      x.Add( new svm_node() { index = j, value = attributeValue });
   }
   vx.Add(x.ToArray());
}
var data_set= new svm_problem();
data_set.l = vy.Count;
data_set.x = vx.ToArray();
data_set.y = vy.ToArray();
var svm = new C_SVC(data_set, [most_appropriate_Kernel], c_parameter);
```